# bootstrap navbar is not displaying the nav bar properly. and is not responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have the following bootstrap navbar snippet. It is not rendering properly and it is not responsive.

How do I make it responsive when the browser is resized, when the browser is zoom in or zoom out and when the browser size is reduced?

When I click on the navbar button its not working.

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="en">
            <head>

                 <meta charset="utf-8">
                 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge, chrome=1">
                 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
                    <!-- <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> -->
                 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3.css">
                 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
                 <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

            </head>

            <body>

                <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
                    <div class="container">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/homepage/index"><img src="https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/elasticbeanstalk-ap-southeast-1-419372602220/Customer_Banner+(2).jpg" height="50px"></a>
                        <div class="navbar-collapse navbar-responsive-collapse collapse" style="height: 0.571428596973419px;">

                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                <li><a href="/admins/sign_in">Sign In</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://workpro.co.in" target="_blank">WorkPro</a></li>
                                <!-- <li><a href="WorkPro.co.in">WorkPro</a></li> -->
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </body>
            </html>
```

[here is the fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/fmx06sxa/)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to include bootstrap.js:

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

oraz jquery:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include bootstrap.js and jQuery

http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

> jQuery required
>
> Please note that all JavaScript plugins require jQuery to be included,
>   as shown in the starter template. Consult our bower.json to see which
>   versions of jQuery are supported.

Answer (score 0):

You have written wrong syntax, that's why its not rendering properly

and you missed - **navbar-header div.**
Check the proper syntax on [official bootstrap docs.](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
            </li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
            </li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
            </li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

In css

```
    .nav a {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
}

    .nav a:hover {
        color: #A94245; /*border: 1px solid #A94245;*/
        font-weight: bold;
        background-color: #E8CDC2 !important; 
    }

.nav li {
    border-top: 1px solid #B27D7D;
}

    .nav li:hover {
        border-top: 1px solid #A94245; /*border-bottom:1px solid #A94245;*/
        background-color: #E8CDC2 !important;
    }

.navbar {
    min-height: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    border: 0px;
}

#navbar {
    background-color: #A94245;
}

.navbar-default {
    background-color: #A94245;
}
```

In code:

```
<div class="navbar-header">
                <header role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default">
                    <button type="button" data-target="#navbar" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle ">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>

                </header>
            </div>
            <!-- Collection of nav links and other content for toggling -->
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse out ">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                 <li><a href="Home.aspx">Home</a> </li>
                 <li><a href="/admins/sign_in">Sign In</a></li>
                 <li><a href="http://workpro.co.in" target="_blank">WorkPro</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                </ul>

            </div>
```

The script and css files used are:

```
 <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/javascript" />
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.JS"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```